# Include template in angular-datatables not rendering

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datatable

I am using [angular-datatables](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/) plugin to add datatables to my project. In this, I have a column `Actions` where I want to add some buttons. For this, I am using ng-template which is defined on the same page. **The problem is that the template does not always render. It sometimes shows the button, and sometimes it does not.** It never shows the buttons after I make a search.

**controller**

```
$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions().withOption('ajax', {
        url: '/api/department',
        type: 'GET'
    })
    .withDataProp('data')
    .withOption('processing', true)
    .withOption('serverSide', true)
    .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
    .withOption('createdRow', function (row, data, dataIndex) {
        // Recompiling so we can bind Angular directive to the DT
        $compile(angular.element(row).contents())($scope);
    })
    .withBootstrap();
$scope.dtColumns = [
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('id').withTitle('ID'),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('name').withTitle('Name'),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('actions').withTitle('Actions').withOption("searchable", false)
];
```

**view**

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="actions.html">
     <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" ng-click="edit()"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit</button>
     <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" ng-click="delete()"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete</button>
</script>
<div class="hbox hbox-auto-xs hbox-auto-sm" ng-controller="DepartmentsController">
    <div class="bg-light lter b-b wrapper-md">
        <h1 class="m-n font-thin h3">Departments</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper-md">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <button class="btn m-b-md btn-md btn-primary " ui-sref="manager.departments.create">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> <span class="hidden-sm hidden-xs">Add Department</span></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 m-b-xs">
                        <table datatable="" dt-options="dtOptions" dt-columns="dtColumns" class="table table-striped b-t b-b">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th style="width:20%">ID</th>
                                    <th style="width:60%">Name</th>
                                    <th style="width:20%">Actions</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**controller on server side in Laravel**

```
public function index() {
    $departments = Department::company($this->company->id)
            ->select("departments.id", "departments.name");

    return \Datatables::of($departments)
            ->add_column("actions", function($row) {
                return '<div ng-include src="\'actions.html\'"></div>';
            })
            ->make(true);
}
```

I belive this is some syncronization issue. But, I am not getting anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really get any successfully inserted templates? The only way I can get `$compile(angular.element(row).contents())($scope)` to work is when the `<table>` is prebuilt or rendered by `ng-repeat`.

Here delayed injected HTML from a jQuery AJAX needs to be replaced with a `ng-template` including bindings, I think `$scope.$apply()` is the only way around :

```js
.withOption('createdRow', function (row, data, dataIndex) {
   $scope.$apply($compile(angular.element(row).contents())($scope))
 })
```

Works for me -> **http://plnkr.co/edit/UqZKhpgMx7aHCXdaNkiN?p=preview**

---

Silly me. The same can be done in a simple `$timeout`.

```
$timeout(function() {
   $compile(angular.element(row).contents())($scope)
})
```

**http://plnkr.co/edit/5OTeHHUgkIurd6Z3DCkP?p=preview**

Comment: it worked. thanks!! does $scope.$apply cause any performance problems?

Comment: @ShashankJain, you are welcome, thank you for accepting the answer. But I was a kind of silly. See update. A `$timeout` should be enough. After all, all we want is to be _sure_ the `$compile` is performed in a digest later on.. But to answer your question - no, I do not believe a single `$apply` after the dataTable is initialised should cause performance problems at all. Mutiple `$apply` triggered over and over is very bad.

Comment: but, here $scope.$apply is getting called when each row is created. So, if there are say 50 rows in the table, this will get called 50 times.

Comment: @ShashankJain, yes, but only once. It is dataTables that is responsible for rendering the `<table>` (no `ng-repeat`),  so `$compile` _must_ be executed on dataTables internal nodes.